# Javascript Sliding Tab From Right Side Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am almost done creating sliding tabs on this website: http://www.imaginationmuzic.com and the last step is the right side sliding tab is not sliding correctly.  As you can see after it starts open, opens further after one click and seems to close after the 3rd but really makes the site wider allowing the user to scroll to see it hidden...

here is my code:

CSS

```
#panel2{ 
height:500px;
width:200px;
background-color:#333;

 } 
#contact2{ 
position:relative;
 top:-400px;
right:40px;
width:40px; 
height:168px; 
background:url(/images/twitter-panel.png); 

} 
#container2{ 
position:relative;
right:0px;
z-index:5;
position:absolute;
top:110px;
}
```

Javascript

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var pos='in';
$("#contact2").click(function(){
if(pos=='in'){
  $("#container2").animate({right:'200px'
});
  pos='out';
 }
else
{
$("#container2").animate({right:'-200px'
});
pos='in';
} 
});
});


</script>
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="container2">

<div id="panel2"></div> 
<div id="contact2"> </div>
</div>
```

Thank you to anyone who can assist!

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate back to `right: '0'` not `right: '-200px'` if you want it to go back to the original position.

Or you could add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the body to stop the scrolling.

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: more like "overflow-x:hidden;"

as the page has to be scrollable to the vertically.

Comment: I added the code; however it is still starting open.  I would like it to start as a closed tab just like the contact tab on the other side of the page, please.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Then you must change your CSS of `#container2 {right: 0px;}` to `#container2 {right: -200px;}`

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued support its working now however a new error has arisen as the page continues to stretch to the right with the panel, even though the overflow is hidden.

Comment: Which browser are you viewing your website in? It looks ok my end.